# How to visualize error surface in keras?

Tags: keras

We see pretty pictures of error surface with a global minima and convergence of a neural network in many books. How can I visualize something similar in keras i.e containing error surface and how my model is converging to achieve global minimal error? Below is an example image of such illustrations. And [this](https://deeplearning4j.org/building-neural-net-with-dl4j#animation-of-updaters) link has animated illustration of different optimizers. I explored tensorboard log callback for this purpose but could not find any such thing. A little guidance will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pictures and animations are made for didatic purposes, but the error surface is completely unknown (or incredibly complex to be understood or visualized). That's the whole idea behind using gradient descent.

We only know, at a single point, the direction towards which the funcion increases, through getting the current gradient.

You could try to plot the way (line) you're following by getting the weights values at each iteration and the error, but then you'd face another problem: it's a massively multidimensional function. It's not actually a surface. The number of variables is the number of weights you have in the model (often thousands or even millions). This is absolutely impossible to visualize or even conceive as a visual thing.

To plot such a surface, you'd have to manually change all thousands of weights to get the error for each arrangement. Besides the "impossible to visualize" problem, this would be excessively time consuming.